# url mapping in code igniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter

I'm writing a PHP application using codeigniter framework. I'm trying to add a tool to download the data in the page as a .csv format file. I have the code to the server side, but I'm having trouble handling the URL mapping for the "Download" Controller.
in /controllers/ I have a controller called "Download", which is has a function called 'exportCSV', which receives a json object that is decoded and used to create the file. So, I'm trying to send a JavaScript array through 'post' to that method, but I'm having trouble handling the URL mapping.
here is my javascript call ...

```
function download(){

$.post('index.php/download/exportCSV', {input : dataForDownload.toString()},

              function(answer){
                  alert(answer);
            }
       );
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what problems you're having?  Are you getting a 404 on the POST?

Comment: Where is your controller code? What errors are you getting? whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POST to `index.php/download/exportcsv`. CI doesn't much like Mixed Case controllers.

If you have a download controller, it should look like this:

class Download extends CI_Controller
{
    function _*construct()
    {
        parent::*_construct();
    }

```
function exportcsv()
{
    if($this->input->post())
    {
        // Something was POSTed, continue

        // process input

    } else {
        // Catch error if no POST
    }
}
```

}

If you're getting a 404, your application might not be set up correctly. Check `routes.php` and your `base_url`.

I also recommend the CodeIgniter user guide. It's full of good information:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html
- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html